# Unable to translate buttons on attempt to edit help center root page

Tags: bug, edits, help-center, localization

Moderators can edit some help pages. For instance [root one](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help). There're two buttons in edit mode (Save changes,  Cancel) that don't have source strings in Traducir to translate:

> [image]